# Sending string from java client to c# server in LAN

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I have a small task to send message from java to the following server (the server code is given by my teacher) all in LAN at my house:

**Server (C#)**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 25001);
        server.Start();
        // as long as we're not pending a cancellation, let's keep accepting requests
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

        StreamReader clientIn = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

        string msg;
        while ((msg = clientIn.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }
```

I suspected that something is wrong with this server code, since I didn't succeeded to send it a message, but I succeeded to send to the [following server](https://www.careerbless.com/samplecodes/java/beginners/socket/SocketBasic1.php) message.

**Client (Java):**

```
try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIp);
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, serverPort);
                //sends the message to the server
                PrintWriter   mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                Log.d(TAG, "Sending: " + message);
                mBufferOut.println(message);
                mBufferOut.flush();
                socket.close();
            }catch (Exception e){}
```

maybe it's because I can't send from to java client to c# server? or the teacher's code doesn't work well? I'm just wondering if the problem is in my code or in my teacher's code.

Comment: The port number on the link is 25000 and the teacher code is 25001.

Comment: @jdweng I changed it to 25001 in both sides (client and server)

Comment: Your server side loop is wrong.check the doc examples on TcpListener https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netframework-4.8#examples

Comment: If it wasn't a school task I would consider a higher level of implementation, like WCF server side